LCD screen with extremely narrow field of view
i want to achieve extremely narrow field of view on an arbitrary large LCD screen with arbitrary pixel density
basically i want the image to be visible only if looked at straight on
any slightest tilt of the screen should make the content appear black or invisible
i want to achieve the effect no matter how far/close the person is standing to the screen
any suggestions?

goggle laptop privacy screen

Are you looking for something with a better performance than what is commercially available?

I think you are looking for a micro louver, which has very small vertical bars to ensure only a viewer looking a normal-incidence (directly in front) sees the pixels.
See here for some description from Belkin:

How do privacy screen protectors work?


Privacy screen protectors use a technology called micro louver to narrow the viewing angle of the screen. Like window blinds that block the view of a Peeping Tom passerby, micro louver films are designed with tiny vertical blinds that narrow the viewing angle, making it hard for anyone to see the content on the screen unless they are directly in front of it. Those viewing from the side or behind the main viewer will see a blurred/dark screen.

These are commonly used on airplane screens, computer/smartphone screen attachments.
Search for privacy screen or micro louver.  You can probably buy a sheet of this and cut to the size you need.  Probably different manufacturers spec different angular dependence.  I would guess the tradeoff is tighter angular dependence → more light blocked even from straight in front (dimmer screen).
